# Can't reconcile votes with candidates

Tags: vb.net

Good morning all,

I'm working on a voting program in Visual Basic (using Visual Studio 2013 if that makes any difference), and I can't seem to get the votes per candidate to function.
This is an assignment so I must use the listbox.DoubleClick event handler for the selected index to tally the votes.

Thus far I have written the entire program to my liking but I cannot get the votes to coincide with the candidates. I think it has to do with this block of code

```
Try
        'Selected candidate gets a vote tallied
        vote(candidateList.SelectedIndex) += 1
        candidateList.SelectedIndex = -1
    Catch exc As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show("Please click on a candidate to vote.", "Attention!")
    End Try
```

My entire project can be seen here if needed - [Voting Machine source code](http://pastebin.com/w7DX688N)

Any idea what will help my program reconcile the data? Or what my error is?
Thank you!

Edit- I've gotten it mostly working now, I get an accurate number of votes per candidate, but now I need to figure out how to get both the candidate name and their total votes in the same listbox.
The above code displays the correct votes in the correct order, but if I try to add the candidateList.selectedItem into the mix it throws an invalid cast exception as the string (candidates name) cannot be converted to an integer. How do I get the selectedItem and increment the count for the selected index? I'm stuck at this point now for most of today and help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I have commented out the StreamReader and StreamWriter lines as they aren't being used. They remain rom a previous attempt at getting this to work.

Comment: After having fixed the error using the methods below, I now get an output of the doubleclick, however it's numerical and not ata all related to the voting.
Ie... If I add three candidates and vote once for two of them and twice for the third, it will output 0 - 5 on newlines. I am utterly confused at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. Many thanks to those that helped me!

```
Imports System.IO
```

Public Class Voting

```
Dim Candidates() As String
Dim votes() As Integer


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Get default values and views for Voting Machine
    resultsList.Visible = False
    candidateList.Location = New Point(143, 71)
    tallyVotes.Enabled = False
    resultsList.Enabled = False
    Label1.Text = "Click 'Nominate Candidate' to enter a candidate, or 'Start Voting'" & vbCrLf & "to end nominations and start the voting."

End Sub

Private Sub candidateList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles candidateList.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub resultsList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles resultsList.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub nominateCandidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nominateCandidate.Click

    'Instructions
    MessageBox.Show("When finished entering candidates, simply press enter on a blank line.", "Instructions")

    'Gather list of Candidates
    Dim candidateName = InputBox("Enter the name of your candidate (first and last name please):", "Candidate Name", "", 500, 500)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    'Loops until a null string is entered signaling the end of input
    Do Until String.IsNullOrEmpty(candidateName)
        ReDim Preserve Candidates(i)
        Candidates(i) = candidateName
        i += 1
        candidateName = InputBox("Enter the name of your candidate (first and last name please):", "Candidate Name", "", 500, 500)
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub startVoting_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startVoting.Click

    'Disable the Nomination button
    nominateCandidate.Enabled = False

    'Enable the tally votes button
    tallyVotes.Enabled = True

    'Set the label text to give instructions for tallying votes.
    Label1.Text = "Vote for a candidate by double-clicking his or her name." & vbCrLf & "End the voting by clicking on 'Tally Votes'."

    'Call sub to display the candidates for voting
    showCandidates()

End Sub

Private Sub tallyVotes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tallyVotes.Click

    'Makes results listbox visible and moves the candidate list to the left
    resultsList.Visible = True
    candidateList.Location = New Point(14, 71)
    'Call the sub to tally the votes and display the winner
    getResults()

End Sub

Private Sub candidateList_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles candidateList.DoubleClick

    'Selected candidate gets a vote tallied
    Try
        'Selected candidate gets a vote tallied
        votes(candidateList.SelectedIndex) += 1
        candidateList.SelectedIndex = -1
    Catch exc As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show("Please click on a candidate to vote.", "Attention!")
    End Try

End Sub

Sub showCandidates()

    'Display the candidates in the listbox and sort alphabetically by last name
    Dim query = From candidate In Candidates
                Let firstName = candidate.Split(" "c)(0)
                Let lastName = candidate.Split(" "c)(1)
                Let name = firstName & " " & lastName
                Order By lastName
                Select name

    For Each Name As String In query
        candidateList.Items.Add(Name)
    Next

    ReDim Preserve votes(candidateList.Items.Count - 1)

End Sub

Sub getResults()

    'Add the results to the  Results Listbox
    For Each i In votes
        resultsList.Items.Add(i)
    Next

    'Declare Winner
    Dim mostVotes As Integer = 0
    For Each item In resultsList.Items
        If item > mostVotes Then
            mostVotes = item
        End If
    Next

    resultsList.SelectedItem = mostVotes
    candidateList.SelectedIndex = resultsList.SelectedIndex

    Dim winner = candidateList.SelectedItem

    MessageBox.Show("The winner is " & winner)

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code. You need to initialize the "vote" array before you start using it. You have this line:

```
 Dim vote() As Integer
```

Which doesn't actually initializes the array of integers. Here are some examples how you could initialize is with a length of 3 or 3 variables.

```
Dim vote(3) As Integer
Dim vote As Integer() = {1,2,3}
```

By the way, it would also be best to check that "candidateList.SelectedIndex" has an actual valid value (isn't -1).

Comment: The problem here is that I have no idea how big the array is going to be. The number of candidates is dependent on how many the user enters, so initializing the vote array would contradict the number of candidates right?

Comment: Probably best to use an other data structure then, such as a List(Of Integer).

Comment: Thank you, both your answer and satraj's helped stop my error, but I'm still stuck on getting the vote tally to reconcile with the selected index. I feel like the line that was throwing the error is the culprit but have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the vote array is declared but not initialized which is causing the NullReferenceException

Please initialize the array with proper dimension, For instance you can do that in your code in "showCandidates()" function as follows,

```
Sub showCandidates()


    'Display the candidates in the listbox and sort alphabetically by last name
    Dim query = From candidate In Candidates
                Let firstName = candidate.Split(" "c)(0)
                Let lastName = candidate.Split(" "c)(1)
                Let name = firstName & " " & lastName
                Order By lastName
                Select name

    For Each Name As String In query
        candidateList.Items.Add(Name)
    Next

 'Initialize the vote array. 
 ReDim Preserve vote(candidateList.Items.Count)


End Sub
```

ReDim the vote array whenever you are adding a candidate to the list box (i-e nominate candidate) otherwise you may get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

Comment: A List(Of Integer) is most likely going to be better for performance instead of using ReDim.